# How to setup Proximus mobile broadband?

Tags: internet-connection, 3g, mobile-broadband

We've got mobile broadband from Proximus, but the software provided with it is for Windows and Mac only.

If I simply plug it in in an Ubuntu laptop, it brings up a wizard which helps you setting everything up. The mobile broadband provider is listed there. Only when I try to connect, it doesn't work. It just keeps trying to connect for a few minutes, but eventually fails.

I've tried entering the PIN and changing the DNS servers, but to no effect. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your provider for the right details of the following items:

1. APN Access Point Name
2. Calling number
3. Username
4. Password

And then correct your settings and try to connect. If it fails you can open terminal and type `tail -f /var/log/syslog/`. This shows you the output of `dmesg` but in real time. There you should see an informative error message and this you can paste to fixee.org or pastebin it. So we can look for a solution.

Comment: The ISP made a screwup. Apparently the SIM card hadn't been activated yet.